# retriving data from aggregate function in the view itself in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following code, and I need to retrieve the average data in the django view itself. But the variable average always isn't defined. Any ideas?

```
cont_rating_tmp = EmployerReviewContractor.objects.filter(reviewed__id = cont.id).aggregate(average=Avg('avg_rate'))

cont.rate=average
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns a dictionary. You can get value in this way:

```
cont_rating_tmp = EmployerReviewContractor.objects.filter(
                         reviewed__id = cont.id
                            ).aggregate(average=Avg('avg_rate')) 

cont.rate=cont_rating_tmp["average"]
```

I copy a saple from [django aggregation doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Max
>>> Book.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
{'price__max': Decimal('81.20')}        <---  the result (a dictionary)
```